# sleep functionality in browser/node js

Tags: javascript, scope

Having a list of number [n1,n2...] I want to print the number then sleep for t1, t2 print(n2) sleep for t2 etc.

I manage to "remember" the scope but the problem is that it waits always 1 second only.
also when i hardcode a larger value eg 2000 it just prints all the numbers.

With promises:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return(
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, ms);
        });
    );
}
    
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    sleep(i*1000).then(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

with setTimeout same result

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    (function(z) {
        setTimeout(
            function(){console.log(z);}, 
            z*1000
        );
    })(i);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    (function(z){
        setTimeout(
            function(){console.log(z);}, 
            z*1000
        );
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: You want to what? Wait after every number, or, as your text indicates, sleep after printing all the numbers?

Comment: print(1) sleep(1sec) print(2) sleep(2sec) etc.

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { await sleep(i * 1000); console.log(i); }`, in an async context

Comment: can you make a snippet ?

Comment: With top level await, you can just in a browser console do `const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)); for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { await sleep(i * 1000); console.log(i); }`, otherwise you'll need to wrap it in an `async` function (top level await e.g. works in chrome, but not FF currently)

Comment: Doing this without `await` is surely possible, but that's one place, where the syntactic sugar really shines, so i'd use it.

Comment: I get sleep nees to be an async function and this didn't work,

Comment: async function sleep ( ms) { 
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)); 
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { await sleep(i * 1000); console.log(i); }

Comment: as mentioned, without top level await, wrap it in an `async` function, and call that: `const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)); (async () => { for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { await sleep(i * 1000); console.log(i); }})();`

Comment: `sleep()` doesn't need to be an async function, the context in which you'd like to use `sleep()` needs to be one, with the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you start all your `Promise`s and `setTimeouts()`s simultaniously, their time will run out basically at the same time.

I see two solutions to your problem:

1. You could *wait* until a `Promise` runs out before continuing your code
2. You could add the delay of the previous `setTimeout()` to the next one's delay

Both solutions run asynchronously, which would free up the callstack for other tasks (which is important to do since JavaScript runs single-threaded). The first solution however is more elegant, and keeps your code more readable. That is why I will only go more in-depth into the first one.

For 1. to work, you need to wrap your code (or at least the asynchronous part) in an asynchronous body to be able to use the `await` keyword. We will use the `await` keyword in combination with a `Promise` and `setTimeout()` just like you used it, but we will *wait* for the `Promise` to be resolved.

In code, this could look like this:
**Note:** That wrapped function expression, which is immediately invoked, is called an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

(async function() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await sleep(i*1000);
  }
})();
```